# Upgrading a built-in package

Tags: ruby-mode

My system has emacs 24.5.1 with a built-in ruby-mode. I want to update to the latest ruby-mode from emacs 25.1 in order to get [improved syntax highlighting](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2016-01/msg00342.html). Upgrading the entire emacs installation is more than I want to chew off (many servers times many users).

I copied the improved ruby-mode.el to my home dir and added to my .emacs file:

```
(load "~/ruby-mode")
```

I get no error messages upon reloading emacs, but also no upgraded ruby-mode (squiggly heredocs still not properly highlighted).

How can I replace the built-in ruby-mode with my own local copy?

Comment: Have you tried adding to load-path (add-to-list 'load-path (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/")). I'm not sure which takes precedence.

Comment: The load should do the trick.  Please give details about how you determined that you have "no upgraded ruby-mode".

Comment: Edited to explain that the squiggly heredocs are still not properly syntax highlighted, which is the reason I was trying to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I've answered a different question. I somehow managed to completely ignore the `~/` in `(load "~/ruby-mode")`.

I've now edited that out of the paths I've used below, in order that what I've written is coherent. It might still be useful info, so I'll not delete it, but it's not what you were asking...

---

Emacs looks for libraries in the directories specified in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `load-path`

By default your home directory is not in that list (and nor would I recommend adding it), so `(load "ruby-mode")` would continue to find and load the default library.

If you do not already have a directory for your own local lisp libraries, I would suggest creating a `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory, and adding that to your load-path like so:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
```

With `ruby-mode.el` in that directory, `(load "ruby-mode")` would then find that version before the default version.

If the newer library works and you wish to roll this out to your multi-user servers, you would use the appropriate `site-lisp` directory on those servers.

Remember to byte-compile it.